# Styling input why the attribute change the behaviour?

Tags: html, css

I have the following inputs :

```css
div.custom_input {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.custom_input input{
    display: block;
    padding: .9em .3em;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

div.custom_input input:focus {
    outline: 0
}

div.custom_input label {
    position: absolute;
    left: .8em;
    top: 1em;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out all;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out all
}

div.custom_input input:focus~label {
    left: .5em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 700
}

div.custom_input input:valid~label {
    left: .5em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 700
}

div.custom_input > label {
    cursor: text;
}

div.custom_input > span {
    position: static !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

div.custom_input span {
    display: block;
    position: relative
}

div.custom_input span:after,
div.custom_input span:before{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .01em;
    height: .2em;
    width: 0;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    transition: .2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease all
}

div.custom_input span:before {
    left: 50%
}

div.custom_input span:after {
    right: 50%
}

div.custom_input input:focus~span:after,
div.custom_input input:focus~span:before{
    width: 50%
}

div.custom_input input:valid~span:after,
div.custom_input input:valid~span:before{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_input">
  <input type="text" id="input1" required>
  <span></span>
  <label for="input1">Label</label>
</div>
<div class="custom_input">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <span></span>
  <label for="input2">Label</label>
</div>
```

It's working well when I add the `required` attribute. I don't understand why, when the attribute `required` is not set, the input style is broken

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you the reason why this is heppening,

you are checking if the input is valid then apply some styling on lable, here in your code

```
  div.custom_input input:valid~label {
    left: .5em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 700
 }
```

and almost same CSS on the bottom-most of your CSS.

```
  div.custom_input input:valid~span:after,
  div.custom_input input:valid~span:before{
      width: 50%;
      background-color: black
  }
```

```css
div.custom_input {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.custom_input input{
    display: block;
    padding: .9em .3em;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}

div.custom_input input:focus {
    outline: 0
}

div.custom_input label {
    position: absolute;
    left: .8em;
    top: 1em;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out all;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out all;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out all
}

div.custom_input input:focus~label {
    left: .5em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 700
}



div.custom_input > label {
    cursor: text;
}

div.custom_input > span {
    position: static !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

div.custom_input span {
    display: block;
    position: relative
}

div.custom_input span:after,
div.custom_input span:before{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .01em;
    height: .2em;
    width: 0;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    transition: .2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease all
}

div.custom_input span:before {
    left: 50%
}

div.custom_input span:after {
    right: 50%
}

div.custom_input input:focus~span:after,
div.custom_input input:focus~span:before{
    width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_input">
  <input type="text" id="input1" required>
  <span></span>
  <label for="input1">Label</label>
</div>
<div class="custom_input">
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <span></span>
  <label for="input2">Label</label>
</div>
```

a great article [about valid](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/) is here, have a look.

if you want that part of code and need my help to fix it, let me know, we will try to fi it with valid part

Comment: Well, got new isuue, when I write some data in the input, the label come back to his initial position

Comment: This code fix it `div.custom_input input:valid~label {
    left: .5em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 700
}` but original error comeback